# internally rewrite subdomain images to main images

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Need to internally rewrite test.example.com/images/* TO example.com/images/*

The location of test.example.com is /sub_ds/test/ in the file structure.

Hope that makes sense.  At the moment linking to /images/test.jpg in the subdomain looks for a file at test.example.com/images/test.jpg which obviously isn't there which is why I am looking for a rewrite.

ADDED :

Current htacess :

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

```
# BEGIN rewrites
RewriteEngine On

# Externally redirect client requests for example.com/sub_ds/<subdomain>/<URLpath> to <subdomain>.example.com/<URLpath>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /sub_ds/
RewriteRule ^sub_ds/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R=301,L]

# Externally redirect client requests for www.[subdomain].example.com/sub_ds/<subdomain>/<URLpath> to <subdomain>.example.com/<URLpath> 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^sub_ds/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R=301,L]

# Externally redirect 'secure' subdomain to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Externally redirect non 'secure' subdomain to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secure\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Externally redirect index.(php|html?) in any location, preserving parameters, to location root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /phpsite/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(([^/]*/)*)index\.(php|html?)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite <subdomain>.example.com/<URLpath> to example.com/sub_ds/<subdomain/<URLpath>
RewriteCond $1 !^sub_ds/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /sub_ds/%1/$1 [L]
```

Goal... to make test.example.com/images/* point to example.com/images/*

Subdomains are physically located as subfolders in root (typically with most setups).  So the test subdomain is physically located at /sub_ds/test/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://example.com/sub_ds/test/images/$1
```

The second link check if the host is exactly example.com (^ means the begining of the host name and $ the ending). The fird line check if the url begins with images/ to do the rewriting.

Comment: There is no way that would work... that would do an internal rewrite for all images in the main domain to the subdomain.  I need to internally rewrite images for subdomains to the main.  For example, test.example.com/images/test.jpg should use the file at example.com/images/test.jpg

Comment: What I want to accomplish is using assets (images, css, js, etc) on subdomains from the main domain so they are all in one location. If I link using relative from root then designing the pages will still act normally (I can see the images for example when designing) and the subdomains still work and appear to all be in their subdomain location.

Comment: Tried that as you were updating and it doesn't work either.  I'm starting to think the check should be for example.com/sub_ds/test/images/* as that is the real file location per se.  Does that make sense?  This subdomain stuff is really messing with my head.